# ClrRuntimeHost->Start not functioning as expected

Tags: c++, clr

So I've create a project that uses a CLRRunTimeHost to suprise suprise host a managed library.

However I've run into a problem. When I run this it works absolutely fine with no hiccups, however after distributing it to a few people the error reports started to flow in. After around 11 hours just today I've figured out the source to be this. The entire function passes through fine, however, upon the last check or

```
hr = pClrRuntimeHost->Start();
```

It fails and doesn't start. I've talked and guided all of the people that are using it through library installs etc. and none can get it to work, I even gave the source to a close friend that has VS2015 installed and he fell victim to the same error.

Here's the full function:

```
ICLRRuntimeHost* StartCLR(LPCWSTR dotNetVersion)
{
HRESULT hr;

ICLRMetaHost* pClrMetaHost = NULL;
ICLRRuntimeInfo* pClrRuntimeInfo = NULL;
ICLRRuntimeHost* pClrRuntimeHost = NULL;

// Get the CLRMetaHost that tells us about .NET on this machine

hr = CLRCreateInstance(CLSID_CLRMetaHost, IID_ICLRMetaHost, (LPVOID*)&pClrMetaHost);
if (hr == S_OK)
{

    // Get the runtime information for the particular version of .NET
    hr = pClrMetaHost->GetRuntime(dotNetVersion, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pClrRuntimeInfo));
    if (hr == S_OK)
    {
        // Check if the specified runtime can be loaded into the process. This
        // method will take into account other runtimes that may already be
        // loaded into the process and set pbLoadable to TRUE if this runtime can
        // be loaded in an in-process side-by-side fashion.
        BOOL fLoadable;
        hr = pClrRuntimeInfo->IsLoadable(&fLoadable);
        if ((hr == S_OK) && fLoadable)
        {
            // Load the CLR into the current process and return a runtime interface
            // pointer.
            hr = pClrRuntimeInfo->GetInterface(CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost,
                IID_PPV_ARGS(&pClrRuntimeHost));
            if (hr == S_OK)
            {
                // Start it. This is okay to call even if the CLR is already running

                hr = pClrRuntimeHost->Start();

                if (hr == S_OK)
                {
                    // Success!
                    return pClrRuntimeHost;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// Cleanup if failed
if (pClrRuntimeHost)
{
    pClrRuntimeHost->Release();
    pClrRuntimeHost = NULL;
}
if (pClrRuntimeInfo)
{
    pClrRuntimeInfo->Release();
    pClrRuntimeInfo = NULL;
}
if (pClrMetaHost)
{
    pClrMetaHost->Release();
    pClrMetaHost = NULL;
}

return NULL;
}
```

And I'm calling it like this:

```
ICLRRuntimeHost* pClr = StartCLR(L"v4.0.30319");
```

Comment: What HRESULT do you get when it fails? Did the .NET runtime record anything in the windows event log? On a side note, your code leaks `ICLRRuntimeInfo` and `ICLRMetaHost` COM objects on success.

Comment: @Brian Reichle I got a 0 hr code.